# stop form request until ajax request completes

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

While doing some coding using ajax, I found a problem. Following is my code snip.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function xmlHttp(){
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        return xmlhttp;
    }

    function addData(a, b, c){
        xmlhttp = xmlHttp();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                alert("Response : " + xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        link = "test.php?a="+a+"&b="+b+"&c="+c;
        xmlhttp.open("GET",link,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
<center>
    <form method="POST" action="?page=search.php">
        <table width="400" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><button onclick="return addData(1,2,3);">Add data</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</center>
```

On button click, the ajax request calls. Before the ajax request completes, the submit occurs. What should be done to wait form submit until the ajax request completes.

I found this link similar to mine.
[Sending an Ajax request before form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263526/sending-an-ajax-request-before-form-submit)

Doing that, my other forms are not sent (other input types). POST array remains empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish that the user should not submit the form until the AJAX request is completed, you can simply disable the form when you send the request and enable it once the response is received. You may additionally show a loading... gif to tell the user that something is going on.

**Update:** You can write it like this. What you need to do is replace SubmitBtnId with the id of the submit button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function xmlHttp(){
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        return xmlhttp;
    }

    function addData(a, b, c){
        xmlhttp = xmlHttp();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                alert("Response : " + xmlhttp.responseText);
                Document.getElementById('SubmitBtnId').disabled=false;
            }
        }
        link = "test.php?a="+a+"&b="+b+"&c="+c;
        Document.getElementById('SubmitBtnId').disabled=true;
        xmlhttp.open("GET",link,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I got what you want to say. But my problem is something different. Clicking the button itself submits the form since the button is inside form tag. So while I click button, I guess ajax call as well as the form submit works together and before ajax call success form gets submitted.

Comment: Is the buttons type is 'submit'? In that case you can remove it. And you can submit the form inside the method handling the AJAX response.